# elasticsearch snapshot fails when nodes in a cluster run in different machines

Tags: elasticsearch

we are using elasticsearch 1.1.1
We have a cluster with 3 nodes and all three nodes are in 3 different machines.
Accessing the cluster, performing index operations work fine.
But when we use snapshot feature to take the backup, it (backup) getting failed.
but if we have all three nodes on the same machine, the snapshot command works fine.
Did anybody face this issue.
I did not include the configuration details here, as the cluster and indexing operations work fine without any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to share your config, including how you registered your snapshot repository, are you using any additional plugins (like for S3 or Azure) and what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a solution, it is a requirement that we should use the NFS

Comment: I also got same Problem on Linux Machine to Take snapshot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120343/on-linux-cannt-register-snapshot-repository-in-elastic-search