# Can't register a snapshot repository in Elasticsearch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.4 and ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.Trying to create a snapshot for Local elasticsearch. I refer this [website](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html)

This website steps are working fine on windows Elasticsearch. If I Register the repository on Ubuntu Elasticsearch. it fired below message.

This Query What I run

```
curl -XPUT http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/_snapshot/es_snap -d '{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/mount/backups/my_backup"
  }
}'
```

I got this Response.

```
{
  "error":"RepositoryException[[es_snap] failed to create repository]; 
            nested: CreationException[Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, org.elasticsearch.common.blobstore.BlobStoreException: 
            Failed to create directory at [
              D:/data/es_snapshot_bkup/es_snapshot_repo]\n  
                at org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository.<init>(Unknown Source)\n  
                while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository\n  
                while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository\n\n1 error
            ]; 
            nested: BlobStoreException[Failed to create directory at [/mount/backups/my_backup]]; ",
  "status":500
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. First create a backup folder(Generally that folder create user home folder)

   ```
   mkdir ~/backup
   ```
2. Give permission for that folder

   ```
   chmod 777 ~/backup
   ```
3. Create a repository (Repository is represent you path)

   ```
   curl -XPUT http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/_snapshot/es_snap -d 
   '{"type":"fs","settings":{"location":"home/user/backup"
   ,"compress":true}}'
   ```
4. Snapshot

   ```
   curl -XPUT "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/_snapshot/en_snap/snapshot_1" -d 
   '{"indices":["index1","index2","index3"],"ignore_unavailable":true,
   "include_global_state": false,}'
   ```
5. Restore

   ```
   curl -XPOST "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/_snapshot/es_snap/snapshot_1/_restore" -d 
   '{"indices":["index1","index2"],"ignore_unavailable":true,
   "include_global_state": false}'
   ```

Comment: I already got this solution bro.. but I asked, Created a repository from Curl command(without mkdir and chmod)

Comment: It seems to me there is the typo in #4 (`en_snap` -> `es_snap`)

Comment: Don't you think having 777 perm in a backup folder is too broad and a security issue?

Comment: You should also give access to elasticsearch user only to warranty isolation.

Comment: thanks. That did definitely help. I would like to know if it can be restored in the same instance but with a different index name?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, and I had to make sure the same path was writable on ALL nodes (as the same user). I mounted the directory directly on one of the nodes, and used nfs to mount on the other ones. To troubleshoot perms, edit /etc/passwd and change the login shell for elasticsearch from /sbin/nolgin to /bin/bash and then run 'su - elasticsearch'. Then try writing a file to the directory. You have to do that on all the nodes.

Comment: Hi @sean., Can you give brief explanation about your Solution.

Comment: The trick is that each node had  to have it mounted and writable. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good. But do you have the appropriate permissions to create a repo at "/mount/backups/my_backup". Try your curl command as a sudo user. It's worth a shot !

Reason why I  think its a permissions issue is because of the following in your error log.
nested: BlobStoreException[Failed to create directory at [/mount/backups/my_backup]]; ","status":500}

Comment: yes.. i know permissions Exception... i also add Sudo word in front of my queries.. it's not working..